# Lineage II C6 AGP error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to play lineage 2 c6 but I got AGP is deactivated error what I can do for this? I tried to do all steps in wine support but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to play after you accept that. I can play when i get that warning, just press ok and then your game shoudl start normaly.